# can we make iOS4 style folders in our app

Tags: iphone, ios4

can we make iOS4 style folders in our iphone app? actually i want that there is a icon on my screen and when clicked on that icon the 4 other icons inside that icon will show like iOS4 style.i.e. the main icon treats like a folder in iOS4. is it possible???

Thanx

Comment: Do you want to add this folder menu to the iPhone springboard? or do you want to create your own menu with icons & folders?

Comment: I want to add my own menu with icons and folders.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anything is possible. There is no API for this, so you will have to design the component and its functionality yourself.

Comment: any idea about how to do this?

Comment: It's going to be tough. If you have questions about how to approach it, my guess is that it is probably too advanced for your skill set.  Perhaps pickup some UIKit development books, look into drag and drop, animations and grid based UI logic.